# Mocking GetHashCode with Moq

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, moq

Can anyone explain why the following test fails?

Both the Assert and the Verify fails.

```
public interface ISomeInterface { }

[TestMethod]
public void FailingTest()
{
    var mock = new Mock<ISomeInterface>();
    mock.Setup(m => m.GetHashCode()).Returns(42);

    int hashCode = mock.Object.GetHashCode();

    mock.Verify(m => m.GetHashCode(), Times.Once());
    Assert.AreEqual(42, hashCode);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a Mock, it creates 2 internal things - Proxy, (generated by Castle framework) which can be cast to your interface and exposed by Object property and Interceptor which will register calls based on the interface you have.

In your scenario, method GetHashCode is not the part of the interface and when you call

```
int hashCode = mock.Object.GetHashCode()
```

the interceptor just can't catch this call because it's configuration is based on the declared interface. It sounds like you are calling GetHashCode of a Proxy but not of your mocked interface. If you try to add GetHashCode method to the interface, test will be passed.